# MySQL transaction rollback on User defined errors

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_fail`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `tablea` (`date`) VALUES (NOW());
    INSERT INTO `tableb` (`date`) VALUES (NOW());
    INSERT INTO `tablec` (`date`) VALUES (NOW()); -- FAIL
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$
```

-- Above procedure is fine, that rollback on SQL Exceptions, but
Can we rollback transaction on validations ?.
Eg. I want to rollback all records if 'date' is not current year or if 'date' is null or some key-value not passed.

Comment: Why not do your validations before you start the transaction?

Comment: I am trying to call another several procedures inside a main stored procedure. I am getting few validation errors from child/inside procedures, so i want to rollback entire transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a signal when you have a validation error. See the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).

Comment: Can we use the SIGNAL with transactions??

Comment: The signal will raise an error, and the error handler will be invoked. So, yes.